# How can i get $_FILES info with dropzone?

Tags: javascript, php, file-upload, dropzone.js, dropzone

My index.php, 
where I have my two forms. The dropzone and another to pass some values ​​to the upload.php file

```
<div class="container" >
        <div class='content'>
            <form action="upload.php" class="dropzone">
            </form>
            <form id="images_form" method="post" action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input type="text" name="action" value="insert" />
            </form> 
        </div>
        <button id='uploadfiles'>Adicionar imagens</button>
    </div>
    <script>
        Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

        var myDropzone = new Dropzone(".dropzone", { 
            autoProcessQueue: false,
            addRemoveLinks: true,
            parallelUploads: 10 // Number of files process at a time (default 2)
        });

        $('#uploadfiles').click(function(){
            myDropzone.processQueue();
            $( "#images_form" ).submit();
            var delay = 1000;
            var url = "http://localhost/dropzone/index.php";
            var timeoutID = setTimeout(function() {
                window.location.href = url;
            }, delay);
        });
    </script>
```

My upload.php:

```
if (!empty($_FILES)) {
$target_file = $target_dir . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
$msg = "";
$con = ligabd();
if ($target_file <> "image/") {
    $stm = $con->prepare("Insert into image(Name) values (?)");
    $stm->bind_param("s", $target_file);            
    if ($stm->execute()){
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target_dir.$_FILES['file']['name'])) {
            $url = "index.php";
            echo '<script>window.location = "'.$url.'";</script>';
        }else{
            $msg = "Error while uploading";
        }
        echo $msg;
    }else{
            echo "<p align='center'>Ocorreu um erro ao tentar registar!</p>";
    }
    $stm->close();
    $con->close();
}
```

These files correctly do what I want, however I want to see the contents of the variable $ _FILES and when I do var_dump ($_FILES) it tells me that it is empty.

Comment: i do not understand what you are trying to do

Comment: @GiacomoM this code is from a test project. I am currently conducting tests to later integrate into the project I am developing. What I intend to do is the following: I have the dropzone form to download images. Then I have a button to add the images. When I click on the button, it redirects me to the file upload.php and there it does the whole process of inserting the files in the database

Comment: *"when I do var_dump ($_FILES) it tells me that it is empty."* - Where in your code did you check for it? Enable error reporting and look at the developer console for possible errors.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner 
in the code I put here is not the echo var_dump ($ _ FILES), but when I put it, nothing happens